# Image 3D rotation OpenCV

Tags: opencv, image-processing, rotation, homography

I need to perform a 3D rotation of a 2D image on x and y axis.
I read that i have to use the Homographic matrix on OpenCV , but i don't know how to set the matrix to perform a common rotation angle. For example 30 degree on x axis or 45° on y axis.

I read this post : [Translating and Rotating an Image in 3D using OpenCV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7019407/translating-and-rotating-an-image-in-3d-using-opencv). I have tried different values of the f but it doesn't work.

I want to know which parameters of the matrix i have to change and how (formula).
Thank you!

Comment: Its a bit late but you can find a very simple working demo-code here:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/6667784/1886124 good luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Follow that [same post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7019407/translating-and-rotating-an-image-in-3d-using-opencv), but replace your rotation matrix. Familiarize yourself with the [Rorigues() function](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/calib3d/doc/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html?highlight=rodrigues#void%20Rodrigues%28InputArray%20src,%20OutputArray%20dst,%20OutputArray%20jacobian%29). You can send it a 1 x 3 array of the x, y, and z rotations. It will give you a a 3 x 3 rotation matrix. Plug this matrix in as the first 3 columns and 3 rows of R (leave the rest the same). If you don't want any translation, make sure you set the variable dist to 0 in the code on that page.