# Matrix RotateAxis in OpenCV

Tags: c#, opencv, directx, mdx

In managed directX is a methode which rotates a matrix around an definied axis. You can also define the rotation angle.

```
Matrix.RotateAxis(Axis, Angle)
```

Now my question is: How can I rebuild this functionality in OpenCV?

Comment: OpenCV has a method for a 2D rotation matrix, but not for 3D. You probably need to construct the matrix on your own. Check the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix#Rotation_matrix_from_axis_and_angle)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Image 3D rotation OpenCV](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14942881/image-3d-rotation-opencv)