# Inverse perspective transformation of a warped image

Tags: c++, opencv, math, perspectivecamera

[@ Iwillnotexist Idonotexist](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2809095/iwillnotexist-idonotexist) presented his code for image perspective transformation (rotations around 3 axes): [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20089412/4583590)

I'm looking for a function (or math) to make an inverse perspective transformation.

Let's make an assumption, that my "input image" is a result of his `warpImage()` function, and all angles (theta, phi and gamma), scale and fovy are also known.

I'm looking for a function (or math) to compute inverse transformation (black border doesn't matter) to get an primary image.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

The basic idea is you need to find the inverse transformation. In the linked question they have `F = P T R1 R2` where `P` is the projective transformation, `T` is a translation, and `R1`, `R2` are two rotations.

Denote `F*` as the inverse transformation. We can the inverse as `F* = R2* R1* T* P*`. Note the order changes. Three of these are easy `R1*` is just another rotation but with the angle negated. So the first inverse rotation would be

```
        cos th    sin th    0    0
R1* =  -sin th    cos th    0    0
            0        0      1    0
            0               0    1
```

Note the signs on the two sin terms are reversed.

The inverse of a translation is just a translation in the opposite direction.

```
       1       0      0      0
T*=    0       1      0      0
       0       0      1      h
       0       0      0      1
```

You can check these calculating T* T which should be the identity matrix.

The trickiest bit is the projective component we have

```
      cot(fv/2)    0             0               0
  P =   0       cot(fv/2)        0               0
        0           0      -(f+n)/(f-n)   -2 f n / (f-n) 
        0           0           -1               0
```

The inverse of this is

```
      tan(fv/2)    0             0               0
  P*=   0       tan(fv/2)        0               0
        0           0            0              -2 
        0           0        (n-f)/(f n)    (f+n)/(f n)
```

[Wolfram alpha inverse with v=fv](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=inverse+%7B%7Bcot%28v%2F2%29%2C0%2C0%2C0%7D%2C%7B0%2Ccot%28v%2F2%29%2C0%2C0%7D%2C%7B0%2C0%2C-%28f%2Bn%29%2F%28f-n%29%2C+-2+f+n%2F%28f-n%29%7D%2C+%7B0%2C0%2C-1%2C+0%7D%7D)

You then need to multiply these together in the reverse order to get the final matrix.

Comment: Thanks a lot, but... It doesn't work... I done everything as you wrote, but unfortunately it works only for rotations around the first axis ("perpendicular to the screen"). When I try to rotate input image around any of two else axes (even for 1 degree), the result image is empty... I calculate inverse matrices R1, R2, R3 (i changed sinus to -sinus), T (i changed -h to h) and P as you wrote... Maybe i don't understand what is "fv" and "v" in your (and in Wolfram Alpha) examples...?

Comment: Ah there was a typo. It should have been `f n` not `f v`. I've amended my answer and undated to Wolfram link.

Comment: Thanks, but... still nothing... I think, that should be also "2 * f * n" instead of "f * n" in the denominator in P(3,2) and P(3,3), shouldn't it? But regardless of it, the transformed image is a little bit weird... Whole image is gray - when I transorm a chessboard image, every pixel in the transformed image has the value 128, so it looks that it is mean value... I don't have any idea, what I do wrong...  It would be great if you or someone would take a look of my code, but I'm not sure where may I put it... (there is too less space in this comment block)...

Answer (score 0):

I also had issues to back-transform my image. 
You need to store the points

```
ptsInPt2f   and   ptsOutPt2f
```

which are computed in the the 'warpMatrix' method.
To back-transform, simply use the same method 
   M = getPerspectiveTransform(ptsOutPt2f, ptsInPt2f);
but with reversed param order (output as first argument, input as second).
Afterwards a simple crop will get rid of all the black.