# Calculate Pitch and Roll and YAW by 4 points detected from a square in Opencv

Tags: c++, opencv, opencv3.1

I have a rectangle picture like this image :

[image: Original Photo]

But after that I took a photo from the camera like this :

[image]

[image: Photo By Camera]

I detected 4 corners of my rectangle by `approxPolyDP`.
The points that I detected are these values:

```
308,25
38,99
147,477
412,466
```

Now how can I calculate Pitch, Roll and Yaw by these 4 points?

Comment: Aren't pitch,roll and yaw angles for 3d objects? In which axis did you rotate your rectangle? I think there is a mistake or I misunderstood.

Comment: It's just a 2d rectangle but I rotated it in 3d axis. I added the real photo so you could see that.

Comment: To do that you need a stereo camera to be able to take deep and also i think with those given 4 coordinates (2d) ıts not possible to calculate

Comment: But if you see we have Pose Estimation for that in opencv but I don't know how can I use from that like this link [link](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d7/d53/tutorial_py_pose.html)

Comment: solvePnp function

Comment: decomposeHomography function

Answer (score 1):

See [How to calculate perspective transform for OpenCV from rotation angles?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17087446/how-to-calculate-perspective-transform-for-opencv-from-rotation-angles). You would have to work backwards from that solution.

Getting the transformation matrix is the easy part using getPerspectiveTransform. Figuring out the pitch, roll, and yaw from that matrix would be solving for angles in the single rotation matrix written here: http://planning.cs.uiuc.edu/node102.html for the respective Euler angles.[image: Formula]