# How do I calculate the pitch and yaw rotations of a 3D disk from its 2D projection?

Tags: opencv, math, image-processing, rotation, ellipse

I want to write an algorithm which calculates the rotation of a 3D disk/circle relative to the image plane.

I want to build an application which would determine the rotation of real world objects with circular shape, using a method described in [this](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/21173312.pdf) paper; which describes the issue using higher level of math.

To test the application, I used the code from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67473573/rectifying-document-with-3d-rotation-at-opencv) to generate synthetic images of a rotated circle.

I use the opencv `fitEllipse` function, which is sufficient using small angles 30-45°. If only pitch or only yaw rotation is applied, I can quite easily and relatively accurately calculate the angle from the arccosine of the minor/major axis of the ellipse, but once both rotations are applied simultaneously, The method fails, and I don't know the mathematical relation between the ellipse's minor/major axes and its rotation. I'm not sure whether the synthetic images are off, or my calculation of the pitch angle is wrong.

```py
import numpy as np
import cv2


def get_3d_rotation_matrix(width, height, theta, phi, gamma, dx, dy, dz):
    w, h = width, height
    d = np.sqrt(w ** 2 + h ** 2)
    # theta = np.deg2rad(theta)
    # phi = np.deg2rad(phi)
    # gamma = np.deg2rad(gamma)
    focal = f = d / (2 * np.sin(gamma) if np.sin(gamma) != 0 else 1)
    dz = focal

    # Projection 2D -> 3D matrix
    A1 = np.array([[1, 0, -w / 2],
                   [0, 1, -h / 2],
                   [0, 0, 1],
                   [0, 0, 1]])

    # Rotation matrices around the X, Y, and Z axis
    RX = np.array([[1, 0, 0, 0],
                   [0, np.cos(theta), -np.sin(theta), 0],
                   [0, np.sin(theta), np.cos(theta), 0],
                   [0, 0, 0, 1]])

    RY = np.array([[np.cos(phi), 0, -np.sin(phi), 0],
                   [0, 1, 0, 0],
                   [np.sin(phi), 0, np.cos(phi), 0],
                   [0, 0, 0, 1]])

    RZ = np.array([[np.cos(gamma), -np.sin(gamma), 0, 0],
                   [np.sin(gamma), np.cos(gamma), 0, 0],
                   [0, 0, 1, 0],
                   [0, 0, 0, 1]])

    # Composed rotation matrix with (RX, RY, RZ)
    R = np.dot(np.dot(RX, RY), RZ)

    # Translation matrix
    T = np.array([[1, 0, 0, dx],
                  [0, 1, 0, dy],
                  [0, 0, 1, dz],
                  [0, 0, 0, 1]])

    # Projection 3D -> 2D matrix
    A2 = np.array([[f, 0, w / 2, 0],
                   [0, f, h / 2, 0],
                   [0, 0, 1, 0]])

    # Final transformation matrix
    return np.dot(A2, np.dot(T, np.dot(R, A1)))

def get_image_3d_rotated(image, theta, phi, gamma, dx, dy, dz):
    height, width = image.shape
    rtheta, rphi, rgamma = np.deg2rad(theta), np.deg2rad(phi), np.deg2rad(gamma)
    mat = get_3d_rotation_matrix(width, height, rtheta, rphi, rgamma, dx, dy, dz)

    return cv2.warpPerspective(image.copy(), mat, (width, height))


def callback(x):
    pass

alpha = 0
beta = 15
gamma = 0
canvas2D = np.zeros((600, 800), dtype=np.uint8)
#canvas2D = cv2.circle(canvas2D, (canvas2D.shape[1]//2, canvas2D.shape[0]//2), 50, 255)
cv2.namedWindow('circleImg')
cv2.createTrackbar('pitch', 'circleImg', 0, 90, callback)
cv2.createTrackbar('yaw', 'circleImg', 0, 90, callback)
cv2.createTrackbar('roll', 'circleImg', 0, 90, callback)
cv2.createTrackbar('radius', 'circleImg', 50, 100, callback)
cv2.setTrackbarPos('pitch', 'circleImg', 0)
cv2.setTrackbarPos('yaw', 'circleImg', 0)
cv2.setTrackbarPos('roll', 'circleImg', 0)

while True:
    canvas2D = np.zeros((1000, 1000), dtype = np.uint8)

    pitch  = cv2.getTrackbarPos('pitch', 'circleImg')
    yaw    = cv2.getTrackbarPos('yaw', 'circleImg')
    roll   = cv2.getTrackbarPos('roll', 'circleImg')
    radius = cv2.getTrackbarPos('radius', 'circleImg')

    cv2.circle(canvas2D, (canvas2D.shape[1] // 2, canvas2D.shape[0] // 2), radius, 255)
    
    rotated_img = get_image_3d_rotated(canvas2D, pitch, yaw, roll, 0, 0, 0)
    
    cv2.imshow('circleImg', rotated_img)
    
    contours, _ = cv2.findContours(rotated_img, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
    if len(contours) > 0:
        if len(contours[0]) > 4:
            ellipse = cv2.fitEllipse(contours[0])
            if ellipse[1][0] > 0 and ellipse[1][1] > 0:
                THETA = np.arccos(ellipse[1][0] / ellipse[1][1])
                FI = ellipse[2] * np.pi / 180
                my_len = ellipse[1][1] / np.cos(FI)
                my_angle = np.arccos(my_len / ellipse[1][1]) * np.pi / 180
                print(my_angle)

                img_contours = np.zeros((rotated_img.shape[0], rotated_img.shape[1], 3), dtype=np.uint8)

                #calculate the offset from the center of the ellipse
                offset_minor_x = ellipse[1][0] / 2 * np.cos((90-ellipse[2]) * np.pi / 180)
                offset_minor_y = ellipse[1][0] / 2 * np.cos(ellipse[2] * np.pi / 180)
                offset_major_x = ellipse[1][1] / 2 * np.cos(ellipse[2] * np.pi / 180)
                offset_major_y = ellipse[1][1] / 2 * np.sin(ellipse[2] * np.pi / 180)

                #start and endpoints of the major and minor axes
                minor_end_x   = int(ellipse[0][0] + offset_minor_x)
                minor_end_y   = int(ellipse[0][0] + offset_minor_y)
                minor_start_x = int(ellipse[0][0] - offset_minor_x)
                minor_start_y = int(ellipse[0][0] - offset_minor_y)

                major_end_x   = int(ellipse[0][1] + offset_major_x)
                major_end_y   = int(ellipse[0][1] - offset_major_y)
                major_start_x = int(ellipse[0][1] - offset_major_x)
                major_start_y = int(ellipse[0][1] + offset_major_y)

                #start and endpoints of major and minor axes
                cv2.circle(img_contours, (minor_start_y, minor_start_x), 2, (0, 255, 0), -1)
                cv2.circle(img_contours, (minor_end_y,   minor_end_x),   2, (0, 0, 255), -1)
                cv2.circle(img_contours, (major_start_y, major_start_x), 2, (0, 255, 0), -1)
                cv2.circle(img_contours, (major_end_y,   major_end_x),   2, (0, 0, 255), -1)

                #draw major and minor axes
                cv2.line(img_contours, [minor_start_y, minor_start_x], [minor_end_y, minor_end_x], (0, 0, 255))
                cv2.line(img_contours, [major_start_y, major_start_x], [major_end_y, major_end_x], (0, 255, 0))

                cv2.ellipse(img_contours, ellipse, (255, 0, 255))

                cv2.putText(img_contours, 'THETA:{:.2f}'.format(THETA*180/np.pi), (100, 50), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 1, (0, 255, 255), 2)

                cv2.imshow('circleImg', img_contours)

    if cv2.waitKey(5) & 0xFF == 27:
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()
        break
```